# Query based on dates

Tags: mysql

I've got the following table/data (example)

Users

```
user_id | email
1       | asd@asd.com
2       | asd2@asd.com
3       | asd3@asd.com
4       | asd4@asd.com
5       | asd5@asd.com
```

Scheduled_Jobs

```
job_id | user_id | date
1      | 1       | 05/09/2019
2      | 1       | 05/10/2019
3      | 1       | 05/11/2019
4      | 1       | 05/12/2019
5      | 2       | 07/10/2019
6      | 2       | 07/11/2019
7      | 2       | 07/12/2019
8      | 3       | 11/07/2019
9      | 4       | 13/10/2019
10     | 4       | 13/11/2019
11     | 5       | 10/10/2019
12     | 5       | 10/11/2019
13     | 5       | 10/12/2019
```

Last_Update

```
update_id | job_id
1         | 1
2         | 2
3         | 3
4         | 5
5         | 9
6         | 11
```

When a user is created a list of scheduled jobs is created too. When a user completes a job the Last_Update table is getting updated.

I'm trying to show a list of users which got unfinished jobs based on date. For example 1-30 days delay: x users, 31-60 days delay: y users etc

Based on the example above here would be the expected result:

```
Number of users with no delayed jobs: 2 (users 1 & 4)
1-30 days delay: 2 (users 2 & 5)
31-60 days delay: 0
Over 60 days delay: 1 (user 3)
```

I'm currently only showing the number of users that got no delayed jobs

```
SELECT u.user_id
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT j.user_id AS completed
  FROM jobs j
  LEFT JOIN last_update lu
    ON lu.job_id = j.job_id
  WHERE j.job_date <= CURDATE()
  AND lu.update_id IS NULL
) AS cj
  ON u.user_id = cj.completed
WHERE cj.completed IS NULL
```

Comment: Please show us your expected result for that sample data.

Comment: What is your reference date?

Comment: @Strawberry Today (curdate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first join the three tables, aggregate by `user_id` and compute,  for each user

- how many unfinished jobs they have
- how many unfinished jobs they have within the last 30 days
- how many unfinished jobs they have within the last 31-60 days

Then, you can add another level of aggreation and count how many users meet each criteria.

Query:

```
select
    sum(cnt_jobs_unfinished = 0) cnt_users_no_unfinished_jobs,
    sum(cnt_jobs_unfinished_30d > 0) cnt_users_unfinished_30d,
    sum(cnt_jobs_unfinished_31_60d > 0) cnt_users_unfinished_31_60d
from (
     select 
        u.user_id,
        sum(l.job_id is null) cnt_jobs_unfinished,
        sum(
            l.job_id is null 
            and j.date >= curdate() - interval 30 day
        ) cnt_jobs_unfinished_30d,
        sum(
            l.job_id is null 
            and j.date < curdate() - interval 30 day
            and j.date >= curdate() - interval 60 day
        ) cnt_jobs_unfinished_31_60d
    from users u
    inner join scheduled_jobs  j
        on  j.date <= curdate()
        and j.user_id = u.user_id
    left join last_update l
        on l.job_id = j.job_id
    group by u.user_id
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f37864e71edcf8ae43e224e6e600318)**

```
cnt_users_no_unfinished_jobs | cnt_users_unfinished_30d | cnt_users_unfinished_31_60d
---------------------------: | -----------------------: | --------------------------:
                           2 |                        2 |                           1
```

Note: I had to modify your sample data so job `8`, for user `3`, has a date within 30-60 days, as it was not the case in your original data).

You can run the subquery independantly to see what it returns:

```
user_id | cnt_jobs_unfinished | cnt_jobs_unfinished_30d | cnt_jobs_unfinished_31_60d
------: | ------------------: | ----------------------: | -------------------------:
      1 |                   0 |                       0 |                          0
      2 |                   1 |                       1 |                          0
      3 |                   1 |                       0 |                          1
      4 |                   0 |                       0 |                          0
      5 |                   1 |                       1 |                          0
```